# Wordpress - Remove auto tags from field content in custom posts type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

NOTE: Previous questions on this subject only relate to content entered into the main Wordpress editor window - NOT custom fields in the admin area. The accepted answers do not answer this question.

This question is specific to removing surplus `<p>` and `<br />` tags within custom fields.

Using Wordpress I know it's pretty simple to remove the `<br/>` and `<p>` tags from the content entered in the editor:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

However, while this deals with content entered in the main post info window, this isn't being applied to markup entered in a 'Types' custom field in a custom post type. There, when content is pasted in, it still gets the auto `<p>` and `<br />` tags.

I can work around this temporarily by altering the core `includes/formatting.php` file:

```
function wpautop($pee, $br = 0) {
```

However, this will get overwritten on future Wordpress upgrades. How can I remove auto `<p>` and `<br/>` tags from any content entered in the Wordpress admin area - specifically custom field areas where the remove_filter on the_content has no effect?